# JQuery remove function problem

Tags: jquery, function, variables

In an external js file, I have this function:

```
//remove a stop
var removeStop = function (){
    $(this).parent('.remove').parent('.stop_actions').parent('.stop').remove();
};
```

And on the page itself, I have this inline script to execute that function on a click:

```
//remove stop
$(".remove a").click(removeStop);
```

But it isn't working. I think there might be a problem with '$(this)' because before I split this up (I previously had both parts together in the external js) everything was working fine.

Thanks,
Brian

edit: there was a typo, the "$" is present in the second code block

Comment: youa re missing the `$` before the second part

Comment: You are missing a `$` at the start of the `(".remove a").click(removeStop);`.. you know that right ?

Comment: did u make sure that `$(this).parent('.remove').parent('.stop_actions').parent('.stop')` is an actual element before removing it?

Comment: can you debug the line where the click function is set to make sure `removeStop` has a value when it is run?  At what point is that code run?  on body load?  on document ready?  immediately?

Comment: it would be really helpful if you could share the HTML as well..

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that [`parent()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parent) (*singular*) only looks for immediate parent (*one level up*) to the current element.

It might be more flexible if you use [`.parents()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parents) (*plural*)

```
$(this).parents('.stop').remove();
```

and if there are multiple nested elements with class `.stop` you should

```
$(this).parents('.stop').eq(0).remove();
```